# Modify the file loaded in the Parent Theme from the Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I am trying to customize a "inc/general-layout.php" file, now in a parent theme, with my own file, in the child theme, but I can't manage to call the proper one.

Here is what I have in the parents function.php file:

```
*  define constants
define('TRANSPORT_THEME_DIR', get_template_directory());
define('TRANSPORT_THEME_URL', get_template_directory_uri());

*  listing of core files
$transport_loading = array(
    'inc/init.php',
    'vendor/vendor.php', 
    'inc/theme-setup.php',
    'inc/widgets/widgets.php',
    'inc/lib/pagination.php',
    'inc/lib/image-resize.php',
    'inc/assets.php',
    'inc/general-layout.php',
    'inc/blog-layout.php',
    'inc/lib/login-form.php',
    'inc/comment.php',
    'inc/metabox/metabox.php',
    'inc/location-filter.php',
    'inc/woocommerce-support.php',
    'inc/plugins-support.php',
);
transport_loader($transport_loading);


 * loader file
function transport_loader($files) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        transport_inclusion($file);
    }
}

 * file inclusion
function transport_inclusion($path, $require = true, $once = true, $return=false){

    //default: require_once
    if($once){
        if($require){
            require_once trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ).$path;
        }
        else{
            include_once trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ).$path;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($require){
            require trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ).$path;
        }
        else{
            if($return){
                return include trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ).$path;

            }
            else{
                include trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ).$path;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at methods to remove actions from a parents functions.php, but do not manage to get it work here. I am sure there may be a simplier way. I'd be glad for any suggestion?

Comment: I believe if you put it in the same place, but inside the child theme, it will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

In your child theme create folder inc and insert there edited copy of general-layout.php. Wordpress will overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, however for some reason the parent theme file is still being called. That is why I was looking at the functions.php to try figure out why.